# Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized

Tags: tomcat, netbeans-7

I have used glassfish server in netbeans, now I changed to tomcat and when I
run my web application that I have created in glassfish gives me the
error :

```
Deployment error:
 Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct
username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat
customizer in the Server Manager.
```

I have added a role with name "manager-script" in conf/tomcat-user.xml
but where is my Server Manager? I did'nt find it.
Please help me.
thanks...

Comment: no, I did'nt. Can you explain a little that what should I change in server.xml.

Comment: comment this block : <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have that code in my conf/server.xml file.What shoud I do now?

Comment: Check the tomcat-users.xml of the "Catalina Base" directory. Right-click Apache Tomcat 6.xx (under Servers) and look for the connection tab. There should be a path called Catalina Base. Browse to it and note the credentials set; default is username: ide and password: tomcat-users. Including:

Make sure you set the same credentials in that Servers dialog. Close it and you are ready to ryme!

Hope this helps!

Comment: cool ! glad that I could be of any help

Answer (score 23):

1. Add below lines in `tomcat-users.xml`.

   ```
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-script,manager-gui"/
   ```
2. Restart tomcat/service.

Comment: Don't forget to restart tomcat service after that or the changes won't take effect.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu with Tomcat 7 and Netbeans 7:

Follow @Satya instructions:

> Check the tomcat-users.xml of the "Catalina Base" directory.
>   (Right-click Apache Tomcat 7.xx (under Servers) and look for the
>   connection tab).

Then you should make sure that your `tomcat-users.xml` has something like this:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
```

(if you want to be **REALLY sure**, although **it is [NOT RECOMMENDED](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)**, you can put in `roles="manager-script,manager-gui,manager-status,manager-jmx"`)

Additionally, you can look for the file `build-impl.xml` under `nbproject` folder and go to line:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Change `debugmode` from `"false"` to `"true"`. This will allow you to see the errors in Netbeans directly.

Finally, I had to **add read permissions `tomcat-users.xml` for tomcat7 ** (it seems that when editing as root the permissions changed) and in the **logs folder of tomcat, add permissions to the user that runs Netbeans** (usually your user). I did it creating a `"development"` group and added my user and `tomcat7` to that group, then I changed the group of the logs giving reading permissions.

Last tip: **start Tomcat doing right-click in the Servers** section in Netbeans instead of running `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` start. That way you will see the logs in the Netbeans console.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your existing registered server instance in netbeans and register a new server instance **with a user**.
Steps:

1. Remove your existing tomcat server instance in from Services ->Servers
2. Then right click on Servers and click Add Server
3. Create a new server instance with a user

Answer (score 2):

NB will try to connect to the Tomcat instance through the proxy if one is specified in IDE settings (Tools|Options|General tab).

So, if you still get this after making the relevant modifications in tomcat-users.xml, check your proxy configuration. Try setting the proxy settings to "No proxy" and then try again. If it works, you have bad proxy settings. "localhost" must be in the "No Proxy Hosts" list. Correct accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run you web but it shows the above error , then it is due to no user information in tomcat_user.xml file(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\conf ), so go there open this file and just write this sentence in the end of the " ...."

```
<user password="123" roles="manager-script,admin" username="pir fahim" />
```

like

```
<tomcat-users>
   .
   .
   .
<user password="123" roles="manager-script,admin" username="pir fahim" /> ///write this at this place in the file
</tomcat-users>
```

now copy the above sentence and paste it in your file just change your name and password, no changes with roles

Answer (score 0):

I really should make this a comment if have enough reputation:

PLEASE the first comment by @Satya advicing to remove  should be ignored (at least on windows - which am sure of). check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591754/1119247) if don't believe me

After many hours on SO I resolved the issue by:

1. Making sure IDE and text editors (notepad++) are launched with Admin rights
2. Edit the %TOMCAT INSTALL DIR%\conf\tomcat-users.xml as directed in earlier answers
   especially this one [on a duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26068219/1119247) and this [too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24118732/1119247)
3. Check that xml file again, I mean properly for syntax errors. Use a good editor for xml, notepad++ help me figured out my error. Thanks to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22270221/1119247)
4. Save the file and start Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

check the proxy settings under **tools > options in the ide.**

selecting **no proxy** resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the other answers - I was adding the user line i.e.

```
<user password="123" roles="manager-script,admin" username="pir fahim" />
```

as people said, but I what I was missing was to simply restart tomcat after that.

Don't forget to restart tomcart service or the changes won't take effect.