# Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role

Tags: jsp

I am using Apache Tomcat server 
I am run JSP file and get  Deployment error.

I follow the  link( [Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241539/access-to-tomcat-server-has-not-been-authorized)) to change tomcat-users.xml file .

My question is how to edit the XML file and update the same name??
I am really need help to sort out this problem..

Thanks,

Rd,
Ganesh

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You open the XML file, edit it, and then save it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try checking your tomcat.user-xml file for acomment character in these section

```html
 <tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="manager"/>
        <role rolename="standard"/>
        <user username="admin" password="pwd" roles="standard,manager"/>
     </tomcat-users>
```