# Tomcat 7 jndi - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException on missing resource

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy a spring application using jndi but I am getting an error.
These are all the details :

server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/SpringMvcDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              username="root" password="myPassword"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringMvcDatabase"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
              maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/SpringMvcDatabase"
   global="jdbc/SpringMvcDatabase"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

</Context>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource"
                     jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/SpringMvcDatabase"
                     expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</beans>
```

Error message that I am getting:

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
[2013-05-16 06:11:34,897] Artifact SimpleSpring23:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
May 16, 2013 6:11:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/Administrator/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
May 16, 2013 6:11:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 16, 2013 6:11:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 16, 2013 6:11:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 852 ms
May 16, 2013 6:11:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 16, 2013 6:11:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
May 16, 2013 6:11:36 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [UserDatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [UserDatabase].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

May 16, 2013 6:11:36 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Failed to start "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm/1.0" realm
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[UserDatabaseRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 17 more

May 16, 2013 6:11:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/mywebapp.war
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/docs
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/examples
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/host-manager
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/manager
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 16, 2013 6:11:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1703 ms
Connected to server
[2013-05-16 06:11:37,996] Artifact SimpleSpring23:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2013-05-16 06:11:38,162] Artifact SimpleSpring23:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you are missing

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
          description="User database that can be updated and saved" 
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
          name="UserDatabase" 
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
```

from your `server.xml` file under `<GlobalNamingResources>`. Did you remove it when you added your own resource?

The element below references a resource that didn't exist.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

Comment: I have not deleted anything, but I will try to add these parts and see if this works.

Comment: In fact , I have deleted this part to replace it with my Resource tag, which was an error as I see.Thank you!

Comment: I see that you are very interested in spring...check my website for a nice spring aop article.

Comment: Does it *have* to be in a `GlobalNamingREsources` Tag, or can it be defined in a context, too?

Comment: @0x89 I don't have much experience with that. Check the `context` configuration and see if it is allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after

1-modifying tomcat-user.xml to add the script role

2-this missing jar error was coming up in the logs: [another stack post on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760773/tomcat-8-cannot-load-website)

3- I removed /conf from line pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" and log was saying that it was trying to authenticate a locked user.

conclusion: Tomcat got corrupted