# Tomcat 8 cannot load website

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

I am a newbie of java servlet programming and learning about this. The tomcat installed on my debian computer can initially display the default sample webpage. But after replacing the loading files in var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT with the example pages, the websites fail to show on port 8080.

Below are the output messages in catalina.out:

```
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:31 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml has finished in 694 ms
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml has finished in 410 ms
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/el-api-3.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml has finished in 395 ms
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:322)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more

Sep 28, 2016 10:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After trying several hours I am just wondering how to solve this TAT.

Comment: it's saying it couldn't find the file. check the directory and configuration?

Comment: Please check if you have extracted properly. Seems like you have a corrupted version. Kindly refer their installation notes for extraction.

Comment: Thanks all! I have solved this problem by reconfigure the web.xml file, there are some errors on the tutorial I was reading.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the exception shows that this `/usr/share/java/jsp-api-2.3.jar` file is not found.it is usually caused by wrong directory or file does not even exist.

Answer (score 21):

you can use `sudo apt-get install libservlet3.1-java` in terminal to get these files

Comment: that works, but why is this happening in first place? Shouldnt tomcat install it if required