# Retrieve data from database based on input form

Tags: html, database, jdbc

I tried to retrieve a data from database. I used jdbc to connect to the database. I have a text field and a submit button. When I type the text in the textfield and click submit, it shows a blank page and there is no error in the console .
I didn't get the data from the database.my database name is new and table name is list. Any solution for this?

```
             <!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>

                  <head>
                    <title>D3</title>
                    <script>
                      function getData() {
                        {
                          xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
                          var id = document.getElementById("input").value;
                          var url = "main.jsp"; 
                          url = url + "?input=" + id;
                          xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
                          xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                        }
                        xmlHttp.send(null);


                        function stateChanged() {
                          if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 || 
                      xmlHttp.readyState === "complete") {
                            var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
                            document.getElementById("input").value
                         = showdata;

                          }
                        }
                      }
                    </script>
                  </head>

                  <body>
                    <div id="type">
                      <form>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="input">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="submit" 
                name="submit" onclick="getdata();" </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </body>

                  </html>
```

below is the main.jsp file used to get data from the database based on the input form

main.jsp

```
          <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
        <%@page import="java.beans.Statement"%>
        <%
            String ch = request.getParameter("type").toString();
            System.out.println(ch);
            String data ="";
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
           ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new","root","admin321"); 
               PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement
          ("select * from list where input in name=?");



              ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(); 


                while(rs.next())
                {
                    data = rs.getString("name") + ": " +
              rs.getString("child name");
                }
                out.println(data);
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        %>
```

updated script:

```
           function getData(){ 
              {
            xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
             var id=document.getElementById("input").value;
         var url="main.jsp";
     //  java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
      //  url=URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
         url=url+"?input="+id;


       xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged ;
              xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
           }
         xmlHttp.send(null);


        function stateChanged(){ 
     if(xmlHttp.readyState===4 || xmlHttp.readyState==="complete"){ 
  var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
   document.getElementById("input").value=showdata;

      }
     } 
      return false;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is making an action, even if you didn't specify it. You should prevent the default event (get of a new page) from happening, or specify that you want to POST data instead of GET.

I am unsure if this is the actual answer but there's a chance this will solve your problem. Use client-side javascript to prevent the form action from happening. An example using jQuery:

```
($(document).ready(function(){
$(".your-form").submit(function(e){
   // e stands for the event generated by the submit
   e.preventDefault();
   // the rest of your logic
   });
  });
)();
```

Comment: sorry.still its blank

Answer (score 0):

I could find the following issues with your code.

- I could not find anywhere in the jsp code where you set values for the 'name' attribute after the prepared statement.
- The `String ch = request.getParameter("type").toString();` gets the value of `type` parameter. However in the line `url = url + "?input=" + id;` you are setting the `input` parameter.
- There is no `return false` at the of the `getdata()` to prevent form submit. Add `return false;` to the end of the `getdata()` function
  Try solving the above issues and check if you are still not getting the desired output.

Comment: still the page is blank

Comment: Set the parameter for the prepared statement as well. Let me know if it works.

Comment: st.setString(1, ch);

Comment: it results in blank page

Comment: submit button take me to this url   http://localhost:8080/WebApplication6/index.jsp?input=%26%232949%3B%26%232965%3B%26%232994%3B%26%233021%3B&submit=Submit         is the problem is here?

Comment: As mentioned in @mnemosdev's answer, prevent the default action of form submit. Add a return false at the end of `getdata()` function.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i try the things you suggest but page remains blank.i add the updated script above..plz check.

Comment: Sorry. I think my comment confused you a lot. In the previous code strip just add `return false;` at the end of getdata() code and try.

Comment: when i compile and run there is no error..but when i debug the file it shows the error as fails access denied to manger.

Comment: Can you please tell at which point the error is showing. Is it at the line where you create the jdbc connection? Also, what is 'manger'? Is it a database user?

Comment: this is the error when i debug main.jsp    C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1155: Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.

Comment: in index jsp debug  -java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\localhost.2016-12-23.log (Access is denied)   this is part of my error ..if required i will post whole error..and when i open a manager on local host it shows 403 error without even ask me to type the password...

Comment: whenever I click on that Manager App button it doesn't even bring up the username/password box it just goes straight to the 403 page

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241539/access-to-tomcat-server-has-not-been-authorized